# Next and Previous button as in Mail app

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I need to add two buttons to a UINavigationItem as the next and previous buttons of the Mail app. I'm adding them using setRightBarButtonItems. Easy. The problem is that both buttons have too much space between them, much more than on the Mail app.

I've also tried to use a UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace, but without success.

So, do you have any idea about how to reduce the distance between two buttons on the right side of a navigation item?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is, I doubt the buttons in the mail app are two separate UIBarButtonItems. They are most likely two UIButtons in a UIView set as the rightBarButtonItem using a UIBarButtonItem with custom view.

You can use `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:<# UIView Containing Buttons #>` to create your custom UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! Pending to test